# ¿Cómo agrupar la información de manera bimestral y anual en una misma vista?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente enunciado:

> Crear una vista que muestre la cantidad de productos vendidos por año y bimestre. Año, Bimestre, Total

Esta es una imagen de mi modelo de tablas en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado esta vista por el momento. Aquí está el DDL:

```
create view ventas as
select p.Name as producto ,s.OrderQty, s.ProductID, sum(s.OrderQty) as total,sh.OrderDate 
from SalesOrderHeader sh 
join SalesOrderDetail s on sh.SalesOrderID=s.SalesOrderID 
join Product p on s.ProductID=p.ProductID
group by p.Name,s.OrderQty, s.ProductID, sh.OrderDate
```

Mi problema es que no sé cómo agrupar las ventas de los productos por año y por bimestre, por año podría ser usando `YEAR` pero para el bimestre no sé. He leído que podría hacerse usando un case, pero no sé cómo definirlo.

¿Alguien tendrá una idea de cómo conseguir ese resultado a partir de la consulta que tengo?

Comment: En base a la información que has provisto, he editado la pregunta. Considera esta pregunta como referencia para las nuevas preguntas que publiques en el sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conseguir el bimestre no es directo

[Crear periodos de Meses,Bimestres,Trimestres, Cuatrimestres,Semestres,Anualidad.](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f100/crear-periodos-meses-bimestres-trimestres-cuatrimestres-semestres-anualidad-861654/)

es interesante ver como hace uso del `CASE..WHEN` para ver en que bimestre cae cada mes del año y esto lo usa en el `GROUP BY`

Esa consule aplica el `EXTRACT`, pero en sql server no va a funcionar, por eso hay que cambiarlo al `DATEPART`, algo como ser

```
...
GROUP BY DATEPART (YEAR, sh.OrderDate)
CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART (MONTH, sh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 'B01' 
    WHEN DATEPART (MONTH, sh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 3 AND 4 THEN 'B02'
    WHEN DATEPART (MONTH, sh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 5 AND 6 THEN 'B03'
    WHEN DATEPART (MONTH, sh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 8 THEN 'B04' 
    WHEN DATEPART (MONTH, sh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN 'B05'
    WHEN DATEPART (MONTH, sh.OrderDate) BETWEEN 11 AND 12 THEN 'B06'
END
```

Comment: gracias, algo asi necesitaba XD

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de calcular el "bimestre" sin usar `CASE` puede ser:

```
'B' + CAST((MONTH(sh.OrderDate)+1)/2 AS CHAR(1))
```

Comment: muchas gracias lamak, algo mas avanzado para mi pero muy util, lo tomare en cuenta XD